# Как лучше (красивее) отделить элементы в LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, вёрстка, xml

Имеется интерфейс, который разделен на некоторые разделы. Все они помещены в LinearLayout. Как лучше сделать отступ у них? Видел, что после элементов добавляют как-то черту _________ - типа такой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Хочу сделать так]

Comment: Для этого есть специальные сервисы по дизайну и по расположению элементов.

Comment: @zakiroof, какие?

Comment: [Material design](https://material.io/design/) или [dribble](https://dribbble.com/). Смотрите как это красиво делается и как надо делать. Потом пытаетесь сами сделать, что-то нагуглить. А вот если уже и потом не получиться, то приходите сюда с конкретным вопросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делаю это так, как по мне самый простой способ, с минимальными затратами ресурсов:

```
//separete_line.xml
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
     <corner android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>

//ваша разметка, вставинть нужно в том месте где хотите её видеть
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/separete_line"/>
```

Вместо Shape можно использовать просто установку цвета, но тогда краи будут квадратными, а это не совсем приятно для глаза, хотя всё зависит от вашего дизайна.

Comment: Попробовал, почему-то не вижу на разметке саму линию.

Comment: Должно работать, учитывая что вы используете LinerLayout, проверьте где вы его положили, попробуйте для начала вынести в родительскую разметку, на самый верх.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант горизонтальной черты:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="#a0a0a0"/>
```